# Interpolate Environment Variables using Config::Any and the Config::General Driver

Tags: perl, configuration

How can I Interpolate Environment Variables with [Config::General](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aGeneral) setup with [Config::Any](https://metacpan.org/module/Config%3a%3aAny). This is my config snippet pulled from my [OX](https://metacpan.org/module/OX) application, it returns the data specified in my `.conf` fine, except that I can't get it to recognize environment variables.

```
has config => (
  isa          => 'HashRef',
  is           => 'ro',
  lifecycle    => 'Singleton',
  dependencies => ['config_file'],
  block        => sub {
    my $s = shift;

    my $cfg
        = load_class('Config::Any')->load_files({
            flatten_to_hash => 1,
            use_ext         => 1,
            files           => [ $s->param('config_file') ],
            General         => {
                -InterPolateEnv => 1,
            },
        });

    return $cfg->{ $s->param('config_file') };
  },
);
```

here's a couple of tries for my config

```
<db>
   dsn $PERL_FEEDER_DSN
</db>

<db>
   dsn $ENV{PERL_FEEDER_DSN}
</db>
```

Both of these simply end up with dsn containing the literal `$...`.

I've done this before, but I can't figure out how I did it, or what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify `-InterPolateEnv => 1` in conjunction with `-InterPolateVars => 1` so that `Config::General::Interpolated` is loaded. As I understand it, `-InterPolateEnv => 1` by itself does not trigger the loading of that module. It is an option which that module understands.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::General;

my $conf = new Config::General(
    -ConfigFile      => 'test.conf',
    -InterPolateEnv => 1,
    -InterPolateVars => 1,
);

use YAML;
print Dump { $conf->getall };
```

Config file:

```
<db>
   dsn $PERL_FEEDER_DSN
</db>
```

Output:

```
---
db:
  dsn: testing
```

Comment: isn't tht what this is doing? `  General         => {
                -InterPolateEnv => 1,
            },`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that it needs to be specified in conjunction with `-InterPolateVars => 1` so that `Config::General::Interpolated` is loaded.

Comment: ah, see I could swear that the docs was saying that InterPolateEnv implied InperPolateVars

Comment: According to the documentation, `InterPolateEnv` *does* imply `InperPolateVars` https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::General#InterPolateEnv